# Azure IoT Hub and TTN (The Things Network)

Tags: java, azure, iot

Can I configure Azure IoT hub in such a way I can receive messages from TTN (The Things Network)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure IoTHub doesn't support translating messages from TTN to itself as message broker like @AlexBelotserkovskiy said.

However, you can try to create a program using Azure Services as continous running job for reading and sending messages from TTN to IoTHub, such as [Run Background tasks with WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/).

Answer (score 0):

IoT Hub is the specific queue you may use for sending the messages into with some code (or receiving from), for example. If anything you want to send messages from supports code execution, then you would be able to send it to the IoT Hub.

If it does not support the code execution, but you may get the messages from that source, then i would offer you to create a "broker" that will get the messages and send them to the IoT Hub.